# Can I stop installed apps adding their icon to my homescreen?

Tags: htc-sense, home-screen, htc-sensation

Currently **every** app I install adds a launcher icon to the homescreen.  As my default homescreens are nicely arranged and as a result full, it creates another home screen 'page' to put the icons on.

This is really very annoying as I have to remove both the icon and the newly created screen on every install.

Is there any way to stop apps adding a launcher to the home screen by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Google Play Store application:

- Go into Settings
- Uncheck *Auto-add shortcuts*

That will prevent Google play store from creating shortcuts to the home screen each time a new app is installed.